# self state-changing Probability

Tags: probability

Updated: An experiment yields 5 different outcomes out of which there is one desired outcome. As soon as we reveal the outcome, it changes itself and becomes undesirable. Now, how can we get the desired outcome without revealing it because that would make it modify itself and become undesirable.

Please pardon me, I'm not much familiar with stackexchange and question-framing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unless there is something you haven't mentioned, they can't do it. They will need to throw out the whole lot.